# CSS bug only on refresh with chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

I have an ennoying bug with CSS on my [new site](https://mademoisellebidouille.com/).
This is a random bug with **chrome only**. It appears usually at first visit and **disappears with a refresh (F5) or a window resize**. To make it reappearing, you have to **refresh the page** (sometimes up to 10 times).

When the bug appears, two links ("Blog" and "Qui suis-je") of the menubar are some pixels too low, and outside of the chrome's computer css boxes (in developpers tools).

[image: "Blog" and "Qui suis-je" are some pixels too low]
<sub>(source: [ksxav.net](http://img.ksxav.net/images/9cef242f87cd15f90519c7d84525e0ea.png))</sub>
]

Here is a gif with and without bug :

[image]

After searching on google, I tried the following things :

- Fixing Varnish for avoiding the 304 bug (bug described [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246875))
- I tried to copy all the content of CSS targeted with `@import url(css url)` into the main CSS file (described [here](https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201206/beware_of_import_rules_when_concatenating_css_files/))
- Remove all my custom css
- I was able to reproduce the bug on 4 differents computers (same Chrome version)

Same results. I also see the same thing on the theme's developper's website ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160614192745/http://demo.oboxsites.com:80/handmade/). Remember, sometimes you have to refresh / close and reopen the tab to view it).

Do someone has an idea? The theme's developper says he can't reproduce the bug, but as I said, I saw it on 4 different computers...

Thank you.

Here are informations :

- Chrome 44.0.2403.89, no plugins at all
- Wordpress up to date (4.2.3)
- Theme up to date

Comment: what is your bug? can you please tell us about bug?

Comment: @Leothelion please look at the picture the OP is posting.

Comment: @highqweb, yes i did but still did not get the point? but on developer site i can see the issue.

Comment: got the point..sry.. and m too facing this issue in our one of client's site..working on it too..

Comment: @Leo, i changed the image to put a "better" looking one. Some links of the menu bar are some pixels under the others.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I cant reproduce this bug. But i may recommend you use box-sizing. Please read this: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/. It may help you fix this bug :D

Comment: @j08691, i think he did a lot hard work before posting as question with better explanation. I can be sure this is a bug in chrome and too many people are facing this. so please be kind with op.

Comment: @Leothelion - How was I not kind? I am simply asking for the OP to place the problem code *here* since pointing to his site is counterproductive to future SO visitors as once the issue is resolved this question will lose all value.

Comment: @j08691 I know, I'm currently trying to re-create the bug on cssfiddle but I did not succeeded yet.

Comment: @j08691, sorry but i did not said that you are rude.I can see op already tested and tried a lot things and he posted them with images and brief explanation but still your comment after that so i said please as i have seen people asking que like hell still they are getting answer, upvote but no comment like this so..sorry if my words hurt you.

Comment: As I'm still unable to reproduce it in jsfiddle, I just added a .gif showing the menubar with and without the bug.

Comment: @madoxav did you tried to add box-sizing to your site? `html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  }`

Comment: @highqweb Hmmm, it seems to do the trick on my developpement platform. I don't really know why (i'm reading docs about this), but I feel you'll have to post it as an anwser =)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a vertical alignment issue, but it's probably not.  There are a couple things you can do here, though, to try to force the issue:

1. ## Drop floats

   The `a` child elements within your `li` are floated.  That's not necessary and I'd recommend removing them.

2. ## Fake it

   There's no reason you have to rely on the actual document flow to display this where you want it.  I'm going to warn you in advance, this one feels icky to write but works like a charm.

**On your original `a` elements**

- Copy the text of the `a` to a span, and plop it right next to the other

  **Example**

```
 <a href="/place/on/my/site">Mes chiennes</a>
 <span>Mes chiennes</span>
```

- Set the following CSS rules:

```
 #nav li {
   position: relative;
 }
 #nav li span {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 #nav li a {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

- This is a little bit of voodoo where we make the span reserve the actual space needed for the word, and then force the element to display perfectly centered within the tab.  The `transform` bit just drags it so the center of the element is at the `top` and `left` coordinates you provide, so feel free to play with those to get them where you want them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. The 1st tip did not solved it, and i'm currently looking at the 2nd one.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you. But it's not an "easy" solution as I'll have to modifiy the code at every theme's update. [highqweb's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611749/css-bug-only-on-refresh-with-chrome/31613693?noredirect=1#comment51176731_31611749) seems to be a easier solution as it just implies to add some lines to css.

Comment: @madoxav you could always make an child themes. Your change wont be gone after the themes is updated. More info please read here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes